# How to fetch data from ImmutableMultiDict in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, flask

Hi i am very much new to python programming. Currently i am developing a small application using flask for users to submit data. The form is generated dynamically.I am not using WTForms
Here is the HTML part which is generating the form

```
{% if message %}
            {% for data in message %}
            <tr>
                <th><input type="text" name="matchnumber" value="{{data.get('matchno')}}" readonly></th>
                <th>{{data.get('team1')}}</th>
                <th>vs</th>
                <th>{{data.get('team2')}}</th>
                <th><select name="winner">
                <option value="{{data.get('team1')}}">{{data.get('team1')}}</option>
                <option value="{{data.get('team2')}}">{{data.get('team2')}}</option>
                </select></th>
                <th><input type="number" placeholder="Point" name="point" value="{{request.form.point }}" required min="500" max="1000"></th>  
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        <table>
```

the form is getting generated as expected. It will have minimum of 8 columns, it can also be more based on the response it receives from the data base.
But the real problem is arising when I am trying to receive the form data.The data I receive from the form will again be saved in the database 
This is the python part from where I am trying to handle the response

```
     result=request.form
     result2=result.to_dict(flat=False)
     for key,value in result2.items():
                   print(key,value)
```

the problem is that the first line is giving a ImmutableMultiDict data and I am not able to iterate through the same and even after converting it to a proper dictionary I am not able to extract each field properly
the result variable is having the output as

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('matchnumber', '1'), ('matchnumber', '2'), ('matchnumber', '3'), ('matchnumber', '4'), ('matchnumber', '5'), ('matchnumber', '6'), ('matchnumber', '7'), ('matchnumber', '8'), ('winner', 'Russia'), ('winner', 'Egypt'), ('winner', 'Morocco'), ('winner', 'Portugal'), ('winner', 'France'), ('winner', 'Argentina'), ('winner', 'Peru'), ('winner', 'Croatia'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800'), ('point', '800')])
```

after converting it into a dictionary the variable result2 has this as output

```
{'matchnumber': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'winner': ['Russia', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Portugal', 'France', 'Argentina', 'Peru', 'Croatia'], 'point': ['800', '800', '800', '800', '800', '800', '800', '800']}
```

when i am iterating over the result2 items this is the output that is getting generated

```
matchnumber ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
winner ['Russia', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Portugal', 'France', 'Argentina', 'Peru', 'Croatia']
point ['800', '800', '800', '800', '800', '800', '800', '800']
```

the exact issue that i am facing is i am not able to iterate over the list simultaneously, i tried googleing and find solutions as to how to fetch exactdata from an ImmutableMultiDic but i didnt get any good result
Please any one can suggest me a better way to get the data out of the form.The entire form is going to be dynamic, as it will change based on the date it will keep updating the match list. I am not using any ORM i am using only raw SQL for processing the data
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a bit unclear. What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Shivam , what i want to do is that the last list that i am getting i want to simultaneously iterate over the list and update the data in DB.

Comment: You need data like {'matchnumber':'1','winner':'Russia','point':'800'}....{'matchnumber':'2','winner':'Egypt','point':'800'}...and so on?

Comment: yes...and then i can update the same in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the data in this format:

```
[{'matchnumber': '1', 'winner': 'Russia', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '2', 'winner': 'Egypt', 'point': '800'}, ...]
```

You can try

```
output = []
for i in range(len(result2['matchnumber'])):
    di = {}
    for key in result2.keys():
        di[key] = result2[key][i]
    output.append(di)
print(output)
[{'matchnumber': '1', 'winner': 'Russia', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '2', 'winner': 'Egypt', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '3', 'winner': 'Morocco', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '4', 'winner': 'Portugal', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '5', 'winner': 'France', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '6', 'winner': 'Argentina', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '7', 'winner': 'Peru', 'point': '800'}, {'matchnumber': '8', 'winner': 'Croatia', 'point': '800'}]
```

Then you can iterate over `output` and process each dictionary

Comment: Do mark this answer as the correct one, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, but I wrote the solution by Shivam Singh a bit more compact:

```python
result2 = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
datamap = [ { key : value[i] for key, value in result.items() } for i in range(len(result['matchnumber'])) ]
```